# can't drag a tableview or scrollview into a storyboard viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have an existing view controller derived from UIViewController that I'm trying to drag a view into but the storyboard editor won't let me.  If I create a new viewcontroller in storyboard it will let me and I notice it has some autolayout controls... something the original viewcontroller doesn't have.

I don't want to delete the original view controller and recreate since it already has a lot of the push segues and what not hooked up to it.  How can I get it to allow me to drop views/tableviews onto the storyboard surface of the viewcontroller?

Comment: Maybe you are dropping the tableview onto an object that cannot hold it. You can always drag the tableView object and drop it onto the view object under viewcontroller in the document outline hierarchy. This way you make sure onto which view you are adding the tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to :

- Copy your controller into a new storyboard and test to add a view ?
- Add other element ? Likee UIButton, UISwitch etc... Can you do it or not ?

Have you try to add it like that (**drag & drop on view hierarchy**) ?

[image]

`Autolayout` is a way to manage how views are placing comparing to others views.

You can activate or desactivate by clicking on your viewcontroller and by clicking this checkbox, **it will affect to whole storyboard** :

[image: IB activate autolayout]

Comment: it used to be a collection view controller so I think that was the issue..  I deleted and re-created in the end ... is there a way to make it not behave as a "collection view controller" once the storyboard was created?

Comment: Nope, you've got to create a `viewController` in your storyboard. but you can drag and drop your composant from one to an other (no need to recreate everything).